# Can I sort an array in php using usort on basis of value

Tags: php

I want to sort this array of arrays on the basis of final score, and preserve my keys. Can i use usort ? how ?

```
Array
(
[2253472] => Array
    (
        [noOfDays] => 1
        [bestAns] => 1
        [finalScore] => 13.5
    )

[2253465] => Array
    (
        [noOfDays] => 1
        [bestAns] => 0
        [finalScore] => 50
    )

[2253473] => Array
    (
        [noOfDays] => 1
        [bestAns] => 0
        [finalScore] => 23
    )

[2253471] => Array
    (
        [noOfDays] => 1
        [bestAns] => 0
        [finalScore] => 89
    )

[2253464] => Array
    (
        [noOfDays] => 1
        [bestAns] => 1
        [finalScore] => 0.5
    )

[2253415] => Array
    (
        [noOfDays] => 6
        [bestAns] => 0
        [finalScore] => 0.333
    )
)
```

Comment: Yes you can use `usort` .. can you show us your code so far ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is

```
// Ascending
usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['finalScore'] - $b['finalScore'];
});
```

OR

```
// Descending
usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    return $b['finalScore'] - $a['finalScore'];
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can if not preserving keys, you just need a user defined comparison method.

Use `uasort()` for key preservation : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

**Example:**

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = array(3, 2, 5, 6, 1);

uasort($a, "cmp");
```

**For your array, with some explanation**

```
uasort($array, "cmp");

function cmp($a,$b){
   if ($a['finalScore'] == $b['finalScore'])
    {
        // Same score, keep same
        return 0;
    }
    elseif ($a['finalScore'] > $b['finalScore'])
    {
        // $a has higher score, move $b down array
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        // $a has lower score, move $b up array             
        return 1;
    }
}
```

-1 moves it down, 0 leaves it, 1 pushes it up

Comment: This does not maintain the key of the array. The new array has indexes in increasing order 0 ,1, ... how to preserve the key ?

Comment: Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [noOfDays] => 1
        [bestAns] => 1
        [finalScore] => 13.5
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [noOfDays] => 1
        [bestAns] => 0
        [finalScore] => 50
    ))

Comment: Use `uasort()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php ,  here is a nice table of sorting difference and key preservations: http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: I have scores in decimal extending upto 3-4 decimal places. Does usort not function well for decimal values ?

Comment: uasort has nothing to do with this but your defined comparison function. You make calculations in this method. And in my example it works because it's a simple bigger than, smaller than, equals conditional statement.

Comment: wow you accept the answer which just paste a little bit of code with no explanation so you don't learn anything...ugh.. Why do I even try.

Comment: Well i have understood it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31710/discussion-between-pragya18nsit-and-timmied)